# Bitsadmin vs. Powershell in downloading

Tags: comparison, powershell, batch

So, recently, [I asked a question about downloading a file to a variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789289/how-to-compare-downloaded-content-in-batch) My team previously used powershell to download like this:

```
powershell.exe (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://example.org/example.bat', 'example.bat')
```

However, this question's answer had a new way to download, `bitsadmin`:

```
bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal https://example.org/example.bat
```

Which one should I use? And what pros and cons do they have?

Comment: This pretty much answers your question `BITSAdmin is deprecated and is not guaranteed to be available in future versions of Windows.
Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets.`

Comment: That said, I think I'd use the bits cmdlets io the WebClient. BITS handles network interuptions, pausing and automatically resuming transfers, even after a reboot.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Really? I've seen no official documents documenting the issue.

Comment: It is mentioned in the top of the helpmessage  when you open a command prompt and enter `bitsadmin /? | more` (Using a W10 Laptop - bitsadmin version 3.0)